# How do I turn on and off compositing from the command line?

Tags: 10.10, compiz, command-line

As the question says: how can I turn on/off compositing (like clicking the appropriate option in System→ Preferences→ Appearance→ Visual Effects) using the command-line?

I run Ubuntu desktop 10.10, if that helps.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried running

```
metacity --replace &
```

then again for enabling run

```
compiz --replace &
```

Comment: This seems to do what I want. I'll mark the question as answered, but I'll wait for more answers (if any).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command from command line:

```
gconftool-2 -s '/apps/metacity/general/compositing_manager' --type bool false
```

Comment: Well, it changes the value (as I can verify through `gconf-editor`) but, as expected, it has no effect: `metacity` is not one of the running processes (`compiz` is running).